# How to read mongodb exported Json in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I'm using the following code to export a json from a mongoDB query:

```
 querywith open(r'/Month/Applications_test.json', 'w') as f:
for x in dic:
    json.dump(x, f, default=json_util.default)
```

That is working well and is returning the following json:

```
{
  "_class": "Application",
  "_id": "123",
  "applicationTimeStamp": {
    "$date": 1541466008000
  },
  "createdDateTime": {
    "$date": 1541466008084
  }
}
{
  "_class": "Application",
  "_id": "124",
  "applicationTimeStamp": {
    "$date": 1540080000000
  },
  "createdDateTime": {
    "$date": 1540080000096
  }
}
{
  "_class": "Application",
  "_id": "125",
  "applicationTimeStamp": {
    "$date": 1540080000000
  },
  "createdDateTime": {
    "$date": 1540080000097
  }
}
```

I'm using the following pandas code to try to read it:

```
data_df = pd.read_json(r'/Month/Applications_test.json', lines = True)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

What I want is a pandas dataframe that has:

```
_class      | _id | applicationTimeStamp | createdDateTime
Application | 123 | 10/07/2018           | 10/07/2018
Application | 124 | 10/07/2018           | 10/07/2018
Application | 125 | 10/07/2018           | 10/07/2018
```

How could I read the json above into a pandas dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you paste a small example of the data contained in the file you are using? Or better yet, use `StringIO` to reproduce the error you are getting. Someone else more familiar with this than myself may know the solution without seeing your data, but it wouldn't hurt to post it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with the data? The data in the file is the json posted above

Comment: The data you posted above is the output of code, not the actual data, so I cannot run the code you provided and reproduce the error you are getting. An example of a reproducible code block would be ```json_string = StringIO('''{ "name":"John", "age":100}''')
pd.read_json(json_string, lines=True)``` That will not reproduce an error, but I am unsure of what your file looks like in order to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use read_json in this way:

```
df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf="file_path\json.txt",  typ='frame')
```

it returns a dataframe like:

```
            _class  _id  applicationTimeStamp  createdDateTime
$date  Application  123         1541466008000    1541466008084
```

or:

```
        _class            ...                      createdDateTime
0  Application            ...             {'$date': 1541466008084}
1  Application            ...             {'$date': 1540080000096}
2  Application            ...             {'$date': 1540000000097}
```

then you can convert timestamp.